# element.next() not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, prototypejs

I have one function in that below are few lines:

```
    if(ele.next())
        {
            if(ele.next().className == 'errmark')
                ele.next().remove(); 
        }
```

Now this is working fine with all browsers except one i.e. IE8 and I am getting the error below:

```
Webpage error details
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; CMDTDF; BRI/1)
Timestamp: xxx


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 166
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Somebody please help me..
Thanks..

Comment: updated tags to include prototypejs, per OP's comment on tborychowski's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using jquery (`ele.next()` is jquery syntax);

`ele.next()` will give you a jquery object/element, which does not have `.className` property.
`.className` property is only available in native javascript dom object, which you can access e.g. like this: `ele.next()[0]`

---

You have 2 options here:

**1** Use JavaScript mixed with jQuery (not recommended):

`if (ele.next()[0].className === 'errmark') ele.next().remove();`

**2** Use jQuery (recommended):

`if (ele.next().hasClass('errmark')) ele.next().remove();`

---

And here's the whole block - improved:

```
var next = ele.next();
if (next.length && next.hasClass('errmark')) next.remove();
```

Comment: Hello tborychowski, thanks for giving answer. But i am using prototye.js library.Not a Jquery

Comment: @Pratik - you should put things like that in the question tags; as you see, details like this are important and make a difference to the answer you may get. I'll update the tags for you. :-)

Comment: @Spudley thanks for help me ,actually i have not too much experience about how to use it(question tags). I have just started questions and answer so.....

Comment: I got the solutions for that 
    
    Replace the line
    
    if(ele.next())
    
    with 
    
    if($(ele).next())

Answer (score 0):

PrototypeJS has a method similar to the one mentioned above called `hasClassName()`. `hasClassName()` does what you are trying to do but makes it standard in all browsers that PrototypeJS supports.

http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/hasClassName/

So to improve your javascript

```
if(ele.next())
    {
        if(ele.next().hasClassName('errmark'))
            ele.next().remove(); 
    }
```

Also for what it is worth you CAN access the `.className` property of elements that are extended with PrototypeJS in browsers that support that property.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works

```
ele = $(ele);
var next = ele ? ele.next() : null;
if (next && next.hasClassName('errmark')) {
    next.remove();
}
```

Additional information about `ele` (what it is, which element it points to) also would help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solutions for that Replace the line if(ele.next()) with if($(ele).next())